# Javascript xor 32bit integer issue

Tags: javascript, overflow, xor

I've got issue trying to xor 32bits of 1 (0xffff ffff).
Ex:
0xffffffff^0xfff should be 0xfffff000 but in js I can't declare unsigned int thus I get -4096 or -1000 in hex.

Here is js console output:

```
>0xffffffff^0xfff
<-4096

>(0xffffffff^0xfff).toString(16)
<"-1000"

>0xffffffff.toString(2)
<"11111111111111111111111111111111"

>0xfff.toString(2)
<"111111111111"
```

It formats correctly til I do something with it.
Is there way to process such case correctly?

UPD: I realized that problem is in leading bit, but still don't how to deal with it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

unsigned right shift is helpful for this case

```
>((0xf0000000^0xf)>>>0).toString(16)
<"f000000f"
```